# Changing background image with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I will have a list of images (tiled background type)
I would like to be able to click on an image and make it the background image for the entire body for display purposes.  so far I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       

    //var image = ???; what should be here?

    $('.img1').click(function(){
        $('#body').css('background-image', 'url(images/tiles/tile77.jpg'); //the image url cannot be one single url
        });   

    });
```

my current row of images(just being used to get the script working. The images will be coming from a database later.

```
<div class="threecol"><img class="img1" src="images/tiles/tile39.jpg"></div>
<div class="threecol"><img class="img1" src="images/tiles/tile77.jpg"></div>
<div class="threecol"><img class="img1" src="images/tiles/tile47.jpg"></div>
<div class="threecol last"><img class="img1" src="images/tiles/tile33.jpg"></div>
```

The script works the way I have it, but I need the background image to be the image that I clicked on, not the static one I have here.  I need it to work each time I click on an image.

I admit it, I am clueless as to how to get it to work time after time and also how to configure the script at .css(background-image, ?????) to be dynamic

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grab the `src` attribute of the `.img1` element you just fired the click event on and set that as the URL in your CSS modification to the body element:

```
$('.img1').click(function(){
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + this.src + ')');
});
```

Also there should only ever be a single `body` element in your document, so no need to select it via an ID, just use `$('body')` instead.

Comment: Ok, I see what you are saying.  My body element is body id="body".  That worked perfectly thank you very much.  It didnt seem like it would be this easy